# MSDeploy not able to remote server

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, msdeploy

I have two machines, first one is my development machine and the second one a test machine which is remote. I have IIS and web deploy installed on both. When I do a deployment *locally* with msdeploy command on the either of my development and test machines, my deployment is successful. However when I deploy from development machine to the remote test machine, I receive an error like below:

```
Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("some-remote- server"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.111.32.57:8172
Error count: 1.
```

I am running the following msdeploy command:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\IIS\"Microsoft Web Deploy V3"\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="test.zip" -dest:auto,ComputerName="https://some-remote-machine:8172/MsDeploy.axd" -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="Default Web Site/Admin"
```

Comment: Can you use a telnet or similar command to check the connection from the local and remote machine? If that differs as well, check for (Windows) Firewall or other blocking rules.

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken Na, connection is not a problem, I am able to login to the remote machine. Firewall is off, no ports seem to be blocked, so doesn't seem like connectio.

Comment: Run `netstat -aon` on the remote machine and see what lines are about 8172. You have to make those lines part of your question. You also need to enable remote connections in IIS settings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7#enable-remote-connections-and-configure-identity-credentials

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure you installed the management service on both the machine.

[image]

and it is running and set windows and iis credentials.

[image]

and open the port 8172.

set iis manager user at sit level.

[image]

Configure the web deploy publishing setting.

[image]

You will find the destination URL in the configuration:

[image]

Run command prompt as an administrator and run below command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="c:\abc.zip" -dest:iisApp="authapp/app1",ComputerName="https://servername:8172/msdeploy.axd",UserName='server\Administrator',Password='password',AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:iisApp="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitea" -dest:iisApp="authapp/app1",ComputerName="https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd",UserName='server\Administrator',Password='password',AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted
```